# C# Windows Forms LocalDb .mdf file becomes readonly after installation

Tags: c#, winforms, localdb

I have windows forms project and setup project under the same solution. Windows forms project has an .mdf file for the database. I connect to database as "LocalDb\v11.0". The setup project has all source files of the program and includes the .mdf file too. I install the program to "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\" path. But after the installation, i use the program and i want to delete a record from database, i get this error; 
"failed to update database because the database is read-only"

Comment: Of course, I suppose that you have already checked if the MDF file has the read-only flag. Right?

Comment: in fact no. before the installation, i check the .mdf file's read-only flag through sql server management studio. it is false. and i check again after the installation it becomes true

Comment: Yet another reason why you *should NOT* fiddle around with "free-floating" `.mdf` files and put the database **on the server** where it belongs - and reference it there ....

Comment: @marc_s i know it should be in a server but according to my project i don't need it. ok?

Comment: Let me guess, did you install the MDF file in the same folder of your program (C:\Program Files (x86))?

Comment: yes @Steve. where can i store that?

Comment: Well Not in Program Files. Use the ProgramData folder and a specific subfolder for your application (of course this needs also a change in the connectionstring)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve. It works fine